When running a consolidation test (astm D2435) what is considered a small enough amount of consolidation to move to the next load?
I have been reading my text book and the astm for lab and it talks about the material finishing consolidation (usually 24 hours per load. In the test method it does not show an acceptable amount to proceed to the next loading other than time. If you followed the method as written the test would take 2 weeks, depending on the load and unload sequence. If there is an amount that is considered insignificant enough I feel like the next load can be applied sooner. I know the “rate” will change so the amount that is considered insignificant would change.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
